# How can I set the 'Path' variable in a .desktop file to be relative to the location where the desktop file is located?

Tags: xdg

I want to set the 'Path' variable in a .desktop file relative to the location where the desktop file is located and I can't manage to do that.

When I don't declare it or set it to blank it defaults to my home folder no matter where I run it from; and it doesn't accept values relative to my current location within the file system.

Comment: I've had this problem.  I've found workarounds, although sometimes radically complicated depending upon what you are doing.  Are you using a work around at this time?  If not, I may be able to help with that.  I have not found xdg docs that explain much on this.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is marked for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot set the CWD inside a .desktop file. If you want an application to have a specific CWD, you will need to write a simple wrapper script for the application, that looks something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

(cd /where/you/want/it/to/be && exec your_program)
```

You can replace `your_program` there with `$@` and run the script with your_program as an argument, like `run-in-dir.sh your_program`. This way you can use the same script to wrap any program you want to start in that directory.

Comment: This is incorrect.  The Path key in the .desktop file sets the working directory for the executed program.  But this is not added to the $PATH variable so the full path of the application to be executed must still be provided in the Exec key.

Answer (score 19):

You can kludge around this by using an in-line bash mini-script on your Exec. This will add the .desktop file's path to PATH prior to running your command.

```sh
Exec=bash -c "export PATH=$PATH:`dirname %k`; your_command"
```

%k will be substituted by the path of the desktop file itself. The `dirname` command chops off the filename part, leaving only the directory. Once PATH is set like this, `your_command` can be invoked without a full path.

Comment: I clicked to quick and voted up the wrong one but your solution is perfect.

Comment: this could work great with this other question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3464561/1815624

Answer (score 3):

I used this:

```sh
Exec=bash -c 'cd $(dirname %k) && ./SCRIPT_NAME'
```

The %k is the full name of the .desktop file including its path. It's then used by dirname to get a location and change directory to that location. Finally, now that it's in the right place, it finds the script and runs it.

Answer (score 1):

For directory names with spaces in the name, this finally worked for me:

```
Exec=/bin/bash -c 'cd "$(dirname "$0")"; wine game.exe -windowed' %k
```

Credit to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144428/61349

Comment: Finally, something worked without any issue! https://pastebin.com/SB2EWPRj

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me Ubuntu 14.04:

```
Exec=bash -c "cd %k && ./app.run"
```

Latest [spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables) says that **%k** points to the location of the desktop file:

> %k    - The location of the desktop file as either a URI (if for example gotten from the vfolder system) or a local filename or empty if no location is known.

Comment: This worked for me too with Debian 11.6; example:  Exec=bash -c "cd %k/ArubaKeyLinux/; ./launcher_linux.com"