# How do I configure a local directory in a wine launcher?

Tags: wine, launcher, .desktop

ok, so I'm trying to make a portable launcher for my wine application...

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name= UMC
Type= Application
Terminal=true
Exec= wine ~/data/Python/x86/python.exe loader.py 'x86'
StartupNotify= true
Icon= ~/data/UMC.ico
```

the '~' in my code means the current directory, which can be relocated.
what could I use in place of the '~' that would do what I expect??

Comment: `~` means your *home* directory usually, but it doesn't matter, since `~` isn't evaluated in a desktop file: http://askubuntu.com/a/142239/158442. You might want to look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452746/how-can-i-specify-an-icon-with-a-relative-path-for-a-linux-desktop-entry-file

Comment: yeh, the '~' in my code is literally just a placeholder for what's supposed to be there, but still, even w/o a relative icon, I still need a relative directory compatible with Wine...

Comment: Hmm. You could try manipulating the `%k` parameter, as seen in http://askubuntu.com/a/345123/158442.

Comment: yeh... not sure I did that right: Exec= bash -c `"export PATH=$PATH: 'dirname %k'; wine data/Python/x86/python.exe loader.py 'x86'"`, the terminal just pops up then out, no text... I'm a noob btw :P

Answer (score 2):

Got it working with this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=UMC
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Exec=wine ./data/Python/x86/python.exe loader.py 'x86'
StartupNotify=true
#Icon= ./data/UMC.ico #this one doesn't work
```

I recently stumbled across a [Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1444892&p=9063223#post9063223) which mentioned this.

On the note that I DO have it working, I'm not sure if XFCE might be lending a hand here.
So if this doesn't work for you, check your Desktop Environment and/or Window Manager.